# Turn off the voice notification for emails on GALAXY S4?

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4

So I tried to figure this issue out for my boss and ended up stumped, decided to call Verizon for some assistance however, due to lack of "official literature" (?) the tech was unable to assist me in solving the problem. Turns out if I go into the settings for the actual email account that my boss has connected to his phone and shut off the notifications completely that eliminates the voice from say... "You have one new email... You have five new email... You have eleven new email" but.... if we do that he can't receive any notifications at all. No beep, no vibrate, no standard email dings... there has got to be a way. Someone please help, the voice is driving everyone in the office crazy.

Comment: is talk back enabled in your device

Answer (score 2):

If this is happening to you, you might be in Driving Mode.  You might have not actually switched to Driving Mode physically, but if you've paired (Bluetooth) with you're vehicle, it may automatically switch to Driving mode when you enter the car.

Pull down the notification bar from the top of the screen. If Driving Mode isn't one of the five icons at the top of the screen hit the icon that looks like three little boxes and one set of arrows.

That should open a big list of toggle switches. Look for driving mode and see if it is turned on/lit up. If it is turn it off and the voice notifications should stop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the SAME problem and it turned out to be that my ringtone for incoming calls was set to "Hangouts Video Call".  When I changed that to "VZW Airwaves" the voice announcement for notifications went away.  Perhaps it is coincidence, but every other option I tried failed and tested after each, resetting to how things were before.